# What happens if my armor/weapon proficiencies from my race and class overlap?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, fighter, armor, proficiency

I'm a new D&D 5e player and I'm making a character using both the players handbook and the new Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes book. I was wanting to create a Githyanki Fighter.

I noticed that the fighter class give proficiency to all simple and martial weapons and all armor, while the githyanki race feature "Martial Prodigy" has proficient with light and medium armor and with shortswords, longswords, and greatswords.

Do I double the proficiency of these weapons and armors or what exactly would happen in this case? Do they stack somehow or are they redundant?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I think this question may already be asked [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116682/8610). If the linked question's answer address this question also, the site would rather this question be closed so that all duplicates are directed to the same question. If it doesn't, that's great, too, and maybe the question could be edited to explain how the linked question fails to address this situation? Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: so if I am understanding this correctly nothing happens because my fighter proficiency and the Githyanki's Martial Prodigy trait are one in the same?

Answer (score 12):

**They are redundant**

A proficiency from two different sources do not stack (Player's handbook pg 12 notes that the proficiency bonus can't be added to a single die roll more than once).

So in this case, the proficiencies granted by Martial Prodigy are redundant since you already gain proficiency in those weapons and armor types due to your fighter class.